# Button_Click method no longer works

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am modifying a large (11 page) web form that I inherited from a previous employee.  I am new at ASP and HTML5, etc.  I modified many lines of code, but I haven't touched the button code in either HTML or C#.  The Button_Click method used to work, in that clicking the button would run the form validation code and the data saving code.  Here is the HTML:

```html
<div style="position: relative; float: right">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

And here is the code-behind for Button_Click:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValidationForm())
        {
            SaveData();
        }
    }
```

I put breakpoints inside Button1_Click and the function is never entered.  Is there another way to debug to see what's going on?

Here's the top of the aspx page:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="smacklabProject._default" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
  ...
```

I have not changed the inherits.  I don't even know what inherits does.

Here's the top of the aspx.cs (below using):

```
namespace smacklabProject
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ValidationForm())
            {
                SaveData();
            }
        }
        private void SaveData()
        {
            string study = Study_Dropdown.SelectedValue;
            ...
```

Comment: *web form that I inherited from a previous employee*. Have you changed the page inheritance? Post code for page (aspx + codebehind). At-least top 2 lines from aspx file, and top 2 lines from code behind file, after using statements, where the class definition exists.

Comment: Check the top line in your aspx page it should be something like this `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YOURCODEBEHINDPAGE.aspx.cs" Inherits="YOURPAGENAME.Policies" %>`

Comment: Version control rollback to the version that click event still works then compare the differences.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea.  How do I do that?  I'm using TFS.

Comment: do you have a file called _default.aspx.cs and one called default.aspx.cs without the underscore by any chance?

Comment: No, not that I can tell. Just default.aspx.cs.

Comment: I did a compare with the latest checked-in version and I don't see anything suspicious.  How do I rollback to a previous version without losing the changes I haven't checked in yet?

Comment: @JamesAlesi, did you just miss opening bracket in `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)         }` while copy, or its like this in code?

Comment: As about _How do I rollback to a previous version without losing the changes I haven't checked in yet?_ - you can prepare a shelveset by shelving penging changes, then undo changes. At the time you need your changes back you can search for shelveset and "Unshelve" it.

Comment: I did not rollback but I did get the previous version, and it runs fine.  Then I did a compare with the current version and the only differences are a lot of name changes for controls (the previous author left all the default names for the controls).  I am reluctant to revert back to the previous version because I will lose all the name changes.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and debug?

Comment: Yes, I put a breakpoint inside "Button1_Click".  It is never called.

Answer (score 0):

OK this happened to me once.

So if you're using visual studio, click the button at the top that has the start sign to run it and start debugging.

If you run it by right-clicking it from the solution explorer and selecting the  ***view in browser*** option, it would not consider the back-end code.

I can't comment yet Sadly that's why i had to post this as an answer.

Comment: I have been using the "Run" button in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker solved the problem for me.  There was a hidden text box that had a range validator and a default value that was outside of the range.  So it would always fail validation, but the failure text was hidden.

For reference, never do this:

```html
<p>
  <asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ID="RangeValidator1" ControlToValidate="IPAQ_Q2_Days" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="7" Type="Double" Text="The value must be from 1 to 7" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red" />
</p>
<asp:Label ID="IPAQ_Q2_Days_Label" AssociatedControlID="IPAQ_Q2_Days" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="11" Font-Weight="Normal" Text="Please indicate the number of days you performed vigorous activities at work." runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="IPAQ_Q2_Days" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="___ days per week" Width="200" value="0"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Label>
```